# Move the table of content away from the title page in Rmarkdown / bookdown PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to use the `bookdown` package to generate a pdf document:

```
---
title: "My Book"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
   keep_tex: true
   number_sections: true
---

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

# chapter 1

## section a
## section b

# chapter 2

## section a
## section b
```

Here the table of content will be right in the first page and the `\newpage` commands are ignored.
How could I push the table of content into the next page ?

on the other hand, if I use the `pdf_document` as output the `\newpage` commands will work :

```
---
title: "My Book"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output:
  pdf_document:
   keep_tex: true
   number_sections: true
---

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

# chapter 1

## section a
## section b

# chapter 2

## section a
## section b
```

I need to use the `bookdown` version in order to do the tables and figures cross referencing.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but if you are going for a layout with title on one page, toc on another page etc. it might make more sense to use a latex documentclass like `book` instead of `article`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Where do I set that ?

Comment: You could use `documentclass: 'book' ` in your header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toc you see on the first page is not the one you inserted manually. It was automatically inserted. You can use the `toc: false` option to switch this off.

```
---
title: "My Book"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
   keep_tex: true
   number_sections: true
   toc: false
---

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

# chapter 1

## section a
## section b

# chapter 2

## section a
## section b
```

[image]